# Troubleshooting ssh login failure for AWS EC2 using powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, shell, amazon-ec2, ssh

***Short problem description:*** I had created two new AWS EC2 server instances on Redhat Linux and Ubuntu operating system. I was trying to login to it through SSH via Putty but was getting errors(detailed errors further in question). This is just a short description.

***Detailed problem description:*** I generated a new .pem file after creating a free tier Amazon EC2(Elastic Compute Cloud) server of Ubuntu 20 O.S version. Then I have used `PuttyGen` software in my Windows-10 O.S p.c. While trying to login through putty it was giving me an error as shown in the following error description, due to this I was not able to login to aws machines, I have further investigated the issue and all details of troubleshooting steps are mentioned in detailed manner in this self answered question(other suggestions/solutions are welcome).

***Error's description:***

`"Server refused our key"` On terminal AND `"NO supported authentication method available(server sent:public ke;gssapi-with-mic)"`

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Initial troubleshooting:***

1. My very initial thought was that it could be control M characters in .pem file OR in private key. But when checked key looked fine.
2. Then I thought it could be inbound rule issue, that we are NOT allowed to do ssh to aws server but NO I was wrong when I checked configuration of server I found it was fine and 22 port was there for ssh.
3. Then I thought if .pem file has proper permissions or not  I checked and yes it was having read permissions on all users(whoever has had access to it).

---

Obviously nothing of above worked; enough talks so coming now to actual solution now :)

***ACTUAL FIX with complete steps:***

- Since I am using Windows 10 O.S in my P.C so I have thought to go for any other medium to do `ssh`, hence I tried ***SSH*** with ***powershell*** as follows.

```
PS E:\test> ssh -i "aws_key_generator.pem" ubuntu@singh_server_test.compute.amazonaws.com
```

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE! @ 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'aws_key_generator.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "aws_key_generator.pem": bad permission
```

- Above has given me lot of confidence and shown path to me what to do next. I immediately checked permissions of file again (which was READ and verified as mentioned in my initial troubleshooting column above). Then I saw that other groups are present in permissions and then I removed inheritance by going to `"Right click on .pem file"-->"Properties"-->"Security"-->"Advance"` and disabled “Inheritance” from there.
- Then I only kept "admin" group with READ ONLY permissions to it and saved the properties of file.
- Again I tried to SSH from PUTTY(using private key file generated from PuttyGen mentioned in problem statement) but it failed.
- But when I tried from powershell command(which used .pem file) it had been successful login now.
- Then I su as root and went to /home/ubuntu/.ssh directory and checked authorized_keys file and couldn’t see PUBLIC key inside it.
- So I added Public key generated by `PuttyGen` to ***"authorized_keys"*** and saved it.
- Again I tried to login to server by Putty with passing private key to it and I was successfully able to login now BINGO :)

I have fixed issue with this work around fix and thought to share with all here; other solutions are welcomed too, cheers and Happy learning.

Comment: On Unix systems too `.pem` file should not be readable/writable for group, others

Comment: @anubhava, yes sir, that's correct thank you for mentioning it here, cheers.

Comment: @anubhava, + one more thing sir, I had made pem file read only in my initial troubleshooting but later I figured out that NOT all the group's should be added to it,so I finally kept only admin group with read access them it started working from Powershell cheers.

Comment: If you are providing your own answer to your question, please put the "problem" part in the Question, and then add an Answer to provide the "solution".

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I have added clear headings now in my question, for better understanding thank you, cheers

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are logging into an Ubuntu server.

For that, the username should be `ubuntu`, not `ec2-user`.

Comment: I agree he also did an error about the login but the login step by itself is not even done because of the the other problem : the password is not asked